# how to deserialize JSON into IEnumerable<BaseType> with Newtonsoft JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json.net

given this JSON:

```
[
  {
    "$id": "1",
    "$type": "MyAssembly.ClassA, MyAssembly",
    "Email": "me@here.com",
  },
  {
    "$id": "2",
    "$type": "MyAssembly.ClassB, MyAssembly",
    "Email": "me@here.com",
  }
]
```

and these classes:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public string Email;
}
public class ClassA : BaseClass
{
}
public class ClassB : BaseClass
{
}
```

How can I deserialize the JSON into:

```
IEnumerable<BaseClass> deserialized;
```

I can't use `JsonConvert.Deserialize<IEnumerable<BaseClass>>()` because it complains that `BaseClass` is abstract.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Json.net serialize/deserialize derived types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513042/json-net-serialize-deserialize-derived-types)

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You need:

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
};

string strJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(instance, settings);
```

So the JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[MyAssembly.BaseClass, MyAssembly]], mscorlib",
  "$values": [
    {
      "$id": "1",
      "$type": "MyAssembly.ClassA, MyAssembly",
      "Email": "me@here.com",
    },
    {
      "$id": "2",
      "$type": "MyAssembly.ClassB, MyAssembly",
      "Email": "me@here.com",
    }
  ]
}
```

Then you can deserialize it:

```
BaseClass obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BaseClass>(strJson, settings);
```

Documentation: [**TypeNameHandling setting**](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm)

Comment: @AndrewBullock do you know what the parameters of `$type` are? I found a lot of examples with it but nowhere an explanation. Why do you need to specify `MyAssembly. ClassA` and then again `MyAssembly`? The linked `TypeNameHandling` page doesn't provide an explanation to this mystery either :(

Comment: surely the last line here is incorrect, you have a `List<BaseClass>` that you are trying to deserialize to a `BaseClass`  should the last line not read `var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<BaseClass>>(strJson, settings)`

Comment: is it possible to make this work when       `"$type": "MyAssembly.ClassB, MyAssembly",` is not contained in the json and use custom criteria to determine the derived object type to deserialise to using another criteria?

Comment: @Chinwobble  have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11099466/using-a-custom-type-discriminator-to-tell-json-net-which-type-of-a-class-hierarc

Comment: Be careful, this opens up your endpoint to security issues: https://www.alphabot.com/security/blog/2017/net/How-to-configure-Json.NET-to-create-a-vulnerable-web-API.html

Comment: Good Solution, But before applying read this https://www.alphabot.com/security/blog/2017/net/How-to-configure-Json.NET-to-create-a-vulnerable-web-API.html

Comment: `$type` information should be sanitized for security.  See [TypeNameHandling caution in Newtonsoft Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39565954) for details.

Answer (score 38):

Here is a way to do it without populating $type in the json.

A Json Converter:

```
public class FooConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(BaseFoo));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject jo = JObject.Load(reader);
        if (jo["FooBarBuzz"].Value<string>() == "A")
            return jo.ToObject<AFoo>(serializer);

        if (jo["FooBarBuzz"].Value<string>() == "B")
            return jo.ToObject<BFoo>(serializer);

        return null;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

using it:

```
var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<BaseFoo>>(result, new JsonSerializerSettings() 
{ 
    Converters = { new FooConverter() }
});
```

taken from [here](https://blog.codeinside.eu/2015/03/30/json-dotnet-deserialize-to-abstract-class-or-interface/)

Comment: This answer is excellent, but will error if 'FooBarBuzz' is missing (i.e. you need consistently formatted json). You can also check the field exists as shown here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/19158793/852806

Answer (score 7):

use the following JsonSerializerSettings construct while deserializing :

```
new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects
})
```

Comment: `$type` information should be sanitized for security.  See [TypeNameHandling caution in Newtonsoft Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39565954) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You could also wrap the enumerable in a class:

```
class Wrapper
{
    IEnumerable<BaseClass> classes;
}
```

then serialize and deserialize this.

Comment: I have the same problem as you, and this doesnt work for me (as I already am doing this), it complains for the same reason when you deserialize it.

Answer (score -2):

As I needed only one-side serializer for specific base class (to make API return derived classes properties), I came up with current solution

```
public class CustomConverter : JsonConverter<BaseClass>
{
    private readonly JsonSerializerOptions _serializerOptions;

    public CustomConverter()
    {
        _serializerOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
            IgnoreNullValues = true,
        };
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(BaseClass));
    }

    public override BaseClass Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, BaseClass value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStringValue(JsonSerializer.SerializeToUtf8Bytes(value, value.GetType(), _serializerOptions));
    }
}
```