# newtonsoft json does not serialize derived class properties

Tags: json, serialization, json.net

I have a class structure:

```
public class main
{
derived[Serializable]
    public class Parameters: Service.Parameters {
        public bool a { get; set; }
        public string b { get; set; }
   }
}
```

I am using:

```
string jsonSerializedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model.Parameters, Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects,

            });
```

But the properties a and b not being serialized.
Any idea would be great 
Thank you

Comment: this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513042/json-net-serialize-deserialize-derived-types