# Override constructor in derived class, defined by super-class' interface

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

**Structure**

Class `B` extends Class `A`.
`A` implements Interface `ISerializable`

The `ISerializable`defines a constructor:

```
public A(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
```

I need to write a specifc implementation of this constructor in `B`.

I have tried simply putting the constructor in `B` - but it will not be called.
I can't seem to override it either.

**The simplified problem**

So `A(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)` always gets called instead of `B(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt) : base(info, ctxt)`.

or

`new Base()` does not call `new Derived()`

**The code that calls the (wrong) constructor:**

*UPDATE*

- The objects are treated as objects of A - which might be the problem!

*UPDATE*

```
List<A> list = new List<A>();
list.Add(New B());
string s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);    
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<A>>(s); <--- //it is called from here.
```

Any ideas to solve this inheritance problem?

**Details**

```
public class A: ISerializable
{
public A(int id, string name, string type, string category, string description, string data)
        {
            this.Id = id;
            this.Name = name;
            this.Type = type;
            this.Category = category;
            this.Description = description;
            this.Data = data;
        }

 protected A(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
        {
            Id = (int)info.GetValue("id", typeof(int));
            Name = (String)info.GetValue("name", typeof(string));
            Type = (String)info.GetValue("type", typeof(string));
            Category = (String)info.GetValue("category", typeof(string));
            Description = (String)info.GetValue("description", typeof(string));
            Data = (String)info.GetValue("data", typeof(string));
        }
}

public class B : A
{

public B(int id, string name, string type, string category, string description, string data) : base(id, name, type, category, description, data)
            {
               // specific B code
            }

 protected B(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt) : base(info, ctxt){
    // THIS NEVER GETS CALLED   
   // specific B code
}


}
```

Comment: `ISerializable` does not define a constructor. In fact, no `interface` can define a constructor...

Comment: Well, there must be a constructor taking `SerializationInfo` and `StreamingContext` for the serialization to work.

Comment: Removing it gives the following Exception: `A does not have a valid constructor. To correctly implement ISerializable a constructor that takes SerializationInfo and StreamingContext parameters should be present.`

Comment: Apparently, I was wrong. `ISerializable` is indeed getting a special treatment from the compiler. Sorry.

Comment: Can you show [mcve]?

Comment: @PetSerAl i updated the question, and i believe that the example is complete. `A(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)` gets called instead of `B(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)` where `B` extends `A`.

Comment: You should have `GetObjectData` with that parameter list but not constructor.

Comment: `I have tried simply putting the constructor in B - but it will not be called.` What are your actions when this happens? Show the code.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan I also have `GetObjectData` in `A`. It has nothing to do with the problem of the constructor. :)

Comment: @HamletHakobyan - as i wrote: `A(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)` always gets called instead of `B(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt) : base(info, ctxt)` which is ignored.

Comment: The `A(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)` can't be called by itself. Show the code.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan i updated the question.

Comment: @poke I don't find it related.. But thanks for trying to help.

Comment: @haim770 `ISerializable` has zero special treatment from compiler. OP's question essentially was "Why `new Base()` does not call `new Derived()`" at the time you've made the comment...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov That is not true. I see by break points that the serialization is called from the `JsonConvert.DeSerializeObject`. The question is exactly what i want to achieve. I want to reuse some code from the constructor in `A` with additional code in constructor of `B`.

Comment: Does B have two constructors, B() and the B(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)?

Comment: @StephenZeng Yes. But none of these are called by the deserialization. Only `A(info, ctxt)` gets called...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182343.aspx

Comment: @capcapdk can you show more concrete details of A and B, especially their implementations of constructors?

Comment: @StephenZeng I updated the question with some details of A and B

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - although not strictly a case of the compiler handling ISerializable classes specially, be aware that deserializing a WCF Data Contract class bypasses constructors entirely. They only get fired when the object is created via a "= new" command. When deserializing via WCF the constuctors are not called, principally to prevent initialization code getting called multiple times on a class instance.

Comment: @capcapdk I just quickly tried some similar code and both contructors (SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt) got called. Remember though, in .net base constructor is called before derived class's ones.

Comment: @StephenZeng I don't understand why it is like that... I even tried implementing this: `protected B(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt) : base(info, ctxt){ throw new Exception("test");}` and it does **not** get called...

Comment: @capcapdk is there any exceptions possibly thrown in A's constructor? that will prevent B's gets called. Maybe you can simplify A's constructor see if it works?

Comment: @StephenZeng One extra detail: The Json.DeSerialize is actually not called like in the question. It is called on a `List<A> ` where some of these objects in the list are objects of `B`.

Comment: @haim770 no you were not wrong. constrcutors cannot be defined in interfaces in c#.

Comment: @capcapdk can you show more details of it?

Comment: @StephenZeng I updated the part of the question where the code is called from.

Comment: @capcapdk that's why. It is treated as a type of List<A>.

Comment: @StephenZeng Allright. Then we found the problem ;) How we do solve this? I need the list to be a `List<A>`, so i can't change that.

Comment: @capcapdk I've removed my wrong statement about ISerializable not used by Json.Net .

Comment: (Note that answer to your actual question after you've added [MCVE] - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513042/json-net-serialize-deserialize-derived-types)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you to call some code in derived class in your case. It just tries to give you an option. Without knowing the context I cannot do the judge. [Also check out what is virtual member call](http://stephenzeng.com/Home/View/3).

You can define a virtual method in A, call it in A(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt).

```
public class A : ISerializable
{
    public A(string name)
    {
    }

    public virtual void Foo()
    {
    }

    protected A(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
    {
        Foo();
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

Then in B copy/move some of logic in to the overrided method. When A(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt) gets called B's Foo() will get called as well.

```
public sealed class B : A
{
    public B(string name) : base(name)
    {
    }

    public override void Foo()
    {
        Tag = "B";
    }

    public string Tag { get; set; }

    protected B(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt) : base(info, ctxt)
    {
    }
}
```