# How to store a data from child class in DocumentDB?

Tags: c#, crud, azure-cosmosdb

I have a parent class

```
public class Items{
    public Type FeedType { get; set; }
    public double Rating { get; set; }
}
```

I have two subclasses of this Items

```
public class SingleItemResponse : Items
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
public class MultipletemResponse : Items
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Ids { get; set; }
}
```

I have added a list of SingleItemResponses and MultipleItemResponses to the List of Items.

```
var list = new List<ItemResponse>();
list.add(single); // assume that single is a object of singleItemResponse
list.add(multiple); // assume that multiple is a object of multipleitem
```

I can return the list with all the attributes of singleItemResponse and multipleItemResponse. However, I would like to store and retrieve them in documentDB. The problem is when I try to store them in DocumentDB as IList, they don't keep the values from Single and MultipleFeedItems, in this case it is an ID or Ids.

I would like to know how can I save and retrieve them, the only solution I have right now is to add them together in that ItemResponse but I would like to know if there is a better way without stuffing things.

Comment: You mean storing `list` which contains single and multiple items in _one_ DocumentDB entry or two items to _two_ entries in DocDB separately? If my answer does not point to your problem, please write a comment to me.

Comment: @Youngjae the first one, the list which contains single and multiple items but i can only set the type to base type

Comment: // I editted answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1. Persist json hierarchy**

In case of retrieving, if two derivated objects have distinguishable properties like `Id` and `Ids`, you can compare it in `JObject` first and then create to your types.

```
string collectionName = "YourCollectionName";
Guid id = Guid.Parse("275319a3-d395-46f2-9370-f3eadf691e03"); // Manually set GUID for test purpose.

Uri documentUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(DocumentDbDatabaseNameConfig, collectionName, id.ToString());
Uri collectionUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DocumentDbDatabaseNameConfig, collectionName);

// test variables.
var list = new List<Items>();
list.Add(new SingleItemResponse() { Rating = 2.2d, Id = "id" });
list.Add(new MultipletemResponse() { Rating = 2.2d, Ids = new List<string>() { "ids1", "ids2"}});

JObject jInput = new JObject();
jInput.Add("id", id);
jInput.Add("list", JArray.FromObject(list));

// Store data.
var upsertedResult = _documentDbclient.UpsertDocumentAsync(collectionUri, jInput, null, true).Result;

// Read stored data.
var result = _documentDbclient.ReadDocumentAsync(documentUri).Result;

JObject jResult = (dynamic)result.Resource;

JArray jArray = (JArray) jResult["list"];
foreach (var jElement in jArray)
{
    if (jElement["Id"] != null)
    {
        SingleItemResponse single = (SingleItemResponse)jElement.ToObject(typeof(SingleItemResponse));
        // Do your job with single instance.
    }
    else if (jElement["Ids"] != null)
    {
        MultipletemResponse multiple = (MultipletemResponse)jElement.ToObject(typeof(MultipletemResponse));
        // Do your job with multiple instance.
    }
}
```

In addition, inserted data is as below;

```
{
  "id": "275319a3-d395-46f2-9370-f3eadf691e03",
  "list": [
    {
      "Id": "id",
      "Rating": 2.2
    },
    {
      "Ids": [
        "ids1",
        "ids2"
      ],
      "Rating": 2.2
    }
  ],
  "_rid": "KywuAN7aNQABAAAAAAAAAA==",
  "_self": "dbs/KywuAA==/colls/KywuAN7aNQA=/docs/KywuAN7aNQABAAAAAAAAAA==/",
  "_etag": "\"0000ee05-0000-0000-0000-57ff9ecb0000\"",
  "_attachments": "attachments/",
  "_ts": 1476370121
}
```

**Method 2. Crunch into inline json serialized string**

This method got a hint from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8513042/361100). In my experience, I cannot make correct serialized result that contains its own type in each items. But in theory, it could work.

```
JObject jInput = new JObject();

// Use custom serialize/deserialize setting.
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto
};

JArray jArray = JArray.FromObject(list);
string strJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jArray, settings);

jInput.Add("id", id);
jInput.Add("strJson", strJson); // treat json just like strings.

var upsertedResult = _documentDbclient.UpsertDocumentAsync(collectionUri, jInput, null, true).Result;

var result = _documentDbclient.ReadDocumentAsync(documentUri).Result;
JObject jResult = (dynamic)result.Resource;
jResult.ToString().Dump();

List<Items> obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Items>>(jResult["strJson"].Value<string>(), settings);
```