# How to deserialize a Json into the proper derivatives of my Control class

Tags: c#, json, serialization

Let us say I have the following:

```
public class Parent
{
    public string Id;
}

public class FirstChild:Parent
{
    public string FirstName;
}

public class SecondChild:Parent
{
    public string LastName;
}
```

and I have a Json of type `FirstChild` or `SecondChild`, how can I deserialize it to suitable type without having to check contents of serialized JSON knowing that I cann't control the serialization process?

I have tried the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22486943/5077196), but what I am getting is the `Parent` object (fields of children are gone).

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings 
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All 
};
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Parent>(
    Serialized FirstChild/SecondChild, 
    settings);
```

A Json Sample:

```
{\"firstName\":\"John\",\"id\":\"1\"}
```

Comment: What is the JSON you are trying to deserialise?

Comment: a serialized version of FirstChild or SecondChild

Comment: So what is the point of adding the `IElement` interface here?

Comment: Also, you still need to show the JSON you are trying to deserialise. That is almost certainly the problem.

Comment: Question Updated.

Comment: Yes, as I thought, your JSON is not correct. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

To deserialise derived types correctly using Newtonsoft.Json, the JSON string needs to contain an element with name `$type` and value containing the type name. For example, a correctly serialised `FirstChild` object would look like this:

```
{
  "$type": "Your.Name.Space.FirstChild, Your.Name.Space",
  "FirstName": "Blah",
  "Id": "1"
}
```

To do this, ensure that you serialise with `TypeNameHandling.All`:

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourFirstParentObject, settings);
```

Now your deserialisation code will work correctly.

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean by "$type": "Your.Name.Space.FirstChild, Your.Name.Space"? how can I make it happen? adding it to my model?

Comment: The issue is that it is serialized by a third party library, I can not control the serialization

Comment: Then you either need to tell them to fix that or you need to specify the correct type when deserialising.

Comment: I c, thank you, the library I am using is Masstransit and it is designed to behave like this, so I think updating the serialization is not an option, will try to fix it another way around I guess.

Comment: Are you sure you can't change it? https://gist.github.com/MikeGoldsmith/2e07b64cf25ffd259ec6