# Serializing with variable child

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

I have to consume a Rest API where the content has variable structure in a child list ..

Here is a simplified representation that a *Small Car* has several components:- Window, Engine and Door

```
{
   "ProductCode": 1234,
   "ProductName": "SmallCar",
   "Components": [
      {
          "PartType": "Window",
          "Operation": "Electric",
          "Tinted": true,
      },
      {
          "PartType": "Engine",
          "Capacity": 2000,
          "Cylinders": 6,
          "Layout": "V6"
      },
      {
          "PartType": "Door",
          "DoorStyle": "Standard"
      }
   ]
}
```

My POCO classes are defined as below:-

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductCode {get; set;}
    public string ProductName {get; set;}
    public List<Component> Components {get; set;}
}

public class Component
{
    public string PartType {get; set;}
}

public class Window : Component
{
    public string Operation {get; set;}
    public bool Tinted {get; set;}
}

public class Engine : Component
{
    public int Capacity {get; set;}
    public int Cylinders {get; set;}
    public string Layout {get; set;}
}

public class Door : Component
{
    public string DoorStyle {get; set;}
}
```

During the deserialization, how can I get it to create the appropriate component object (Window, Door, Engine). With `var product = DeserializeObject<Product>(....)` I just get a list of `Components` with `PartType` set, but I need the list to be of each class type according to the `PartType`

Comment: You will need to implement a custom  converter for `PartType`.  and then you could use `JsonConverter(typeof(CustomPartTypeConverter))` on that property.

Comment: Can you control the serialization? If not, I would manually map depending on Component.PartType.

Comment: Could maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513042/json-net-serialize-deserialize-derived-types) help you ?

Comment: You can create a custom [`JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) to deserialize your class hierarchy.  Please see [Deserializing polymorphic json classes without type information using json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19307752/3744182), [Json.Net Serialization of Type with Polymorphic Child Object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29528648/3744182) or [How to implement custom JsonConverter in JSON.NET to deserialize a List of base class objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8030538/3744182) for details.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [Custom Json Converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0) if you are using `system.text.json` and there is an example of how you can do it

```
public class ComponentJsonConverter : JsonConverter<Component>
{
  public override Component Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) 
  {
    var type = JsonDocument.Parse(reader.GetRawText())
      .RootElement.GetProperty("PartType").GetString();
    if (type == "Engine")
      return JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<Engine>(reader.GetRawText());
    ...
  }
    
  public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Component value, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
    writer.WriteStringValue(JsonSerializer.Serialize(value, options));
}
```