# How do I loop through classes effectively in C#

Tags: c#, json, .net, class

hello i have a few classes and i have problem looping through some of the classes to get the values.

eg, i want to know which `sensors` are having issues. sensors comprises of `lidar`, `imu`, `camera1234`. i want so check their status and if their status is not `'good'` then i need to say `'lidar not good'`.

ways that i have thought of:

1. list of classes? but what is the 'Type' for classes?
2. using `Root` class, access the other classes from it, similar to how we do for iterating through properties in classes. but how do i do this?

```
    public class Battery
    {
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Camera1
    {
        public string status { get; set; }
    }

    public class Camera2
    {
        public string status { get; set; }
    }

    public class Camera3
    {
        public string status { get; set; }
    }

    public class Camera4
    {
        public string status { get; set; }
    }

    public class Cpu
    {
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
        public string temperature { get; set; }
        public string ram { get; set; }
        public string utilisation { get; set; }
    }

    public class CurrentJob
    {
        public object job { get; set; }
        public object task { get; set; }
        public object location { get; set; }
    }

    public class Dex
    {
        public CurrentJob current_job { get; set; }
        public Battery battery { get; set; }
        public Gpu gpu { get; set; }
        public Cpu cpu { get; set; }
        public Lidar lidar { get; set; }
        public Camera1 camera1 { get; set; }
        public Camera2 camera2 { get; set; }
        public Camera3 camera3 { get; set; }
        public Camera4 camera4 { get; set; }
        public Imu imu { get; set; }
    }

    public class Gpu
    {
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
        public string memory { get; set; }
        public string utilisation { get; set; }
    }

    public class Imu
    {
        public string status { get; set; }
    }

    public class Lidar
    {
        public string status { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public Dex dex { get; set; }
    }
```

this is my json

```
[
    {"dex":
        {
        "current_job":
            {"job":null, "task": null, "location": null},
        "battery": 
            {"status": "good", "value": "100"},
        "gpu": 
            {"status": "bad", "value": "97", "memory":"60", "utilisation":"83.3"},
        "cpu":
            {"status": "good", "value": "32", "temperature":"37", "ram":"31.5", "utilisation":"26"},
        "lidar": 
            {"status": "good"}, 
        "camera1": 
            {"status": "good"},
        "camera2": 
            {"status": "good"},
        "camera3": 
            {"status": "error"},
        "camera4": 
            {"status": "good"},
        "imu": 
            {"status": "good"}
        }
    }
]
```

after implementing advice from JEremey, this is my updated classes

```
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IO;

namespace CoreBot.CognitiveModels
{
    public class Battery
    {
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Camera1 : SensorComponents
    {
        public string status { get; set; }
    }

    public class Camera2 : SensorComponents
    {
        public string status { get; set; }
    }

    public class Camera3 : SensorComponents
    {
        public string name = "CPU";
        public string status { get; set; }
    }

    public class Camera4 : SensorComponents
    {
        public string status { get; set; }
    }

    public class Cpu
    {
        public string name = "CPU";
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
        public string temperature { get; set; }
        public string ram { get; set; }
        public string utilisation { get; set; }
    }

    public class CurrentJob
    {
        public object job { get; set; }
        public object task { get; set; }
        public object location { get; set; }
    }

    public class Dex
    {
        public CurrentJob current_job { get; set; }
        public Battery battery { get; set; }
        public Gpu gpu { get; set; }
        public Cpu cpu { get; set; }
        public Lidar lidar { get; set; }
        public Camera1 camera1 { get; set; }
        public Camera2 camera2 { get; set; }
        public Camera3 camera3 { get; set; }
        public Camera4 camera4 { get; set; }
        public Imu imu { get; set; }
    }

    public class Gpu
    {
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
        public string memory { get; set; }
        public string utilisation { get; set; }
    }

    public class Imu : SensorComponents
    {
        public string status { get; set; }
    }

    public class Lidar : SensorComponents
    {
        public string status { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public Dex dex { get; set; }
    }

    public class SensorComponents
    {
        public string name { get; set;}
        public string status { get; set;}
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a dictionary

Comment: not sure if the concept of class was correctly understood here.
Wouldn't you want 4 _instances_ (objects) that are "Cameras", hence, of the (one and only) `Camera` class ? And all your `Camera` and `Cpu` and `Battery` could implement a common Interface (like `HasStatus`). Then, you can simply have a collection (lke a List) of references to `HasStatus` objects (`allMyStuff = new List<HasStatus>();`and loop over them. The main point of my comment is the _common interface_ part.

Comment: @Pac0 the classes and data are from a json file

Comment: @ycyc A JSON is just data, it's not actually a classs model. Your job as a C# developer is also to identify what is the proper classes that could be useful for your program and what you are doing with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll throw you a bone. The classes all share a Status Property so create a base class called

```
class Device{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}
```

Now all your classes can derive from it:

```
public class Camera1 : Device
{ ]
```

Then you can have a `List<Device> devices = new();` and iterate over that

```
foreach(var device in devices)
{ 
   if (device.status == "good") 
   {
     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(device.Name + " all good");
   }
   else 
   {       
     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(device.Name + " not good");
   }
}
```

---

It can depend in some scenarios it maybe better to use an Interface:

```
public interface IDevice{
    string GetName();
    string GetStatus();
}
```

Implement these in your classes:

```
public class Camera1 : IDevice
{
    public string GetStatus(){
         return "good";
    }
}
```

Then you could iterate over anything that implements the Interface *(not tested)*:

```
List<IDevice> idevices = new List<IDevice>();
idevices.Add(new Camera1());
idevices.Add(new Camera2());
idevices.Add(new Camera3());

foreach(var device in idevices)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(device.GetStatus());
}
```

Comment: im still facing issues with the loop. i used ```List<SensorComponents> components = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SensorComponents>>(json);``` however, it seems that ```components``` only consist of one item. and ``component.name`` and ```component.status``` is ```null```. i have added my json and updated classes in the question

Comment: @ycyc you need to deserialize like this `var components = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);`   and then you'll hit an error that this Q&A solves: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8513042/495455

Answer (score 2):

Saw that JEremey proposed something good while I was writing, but here is "another bone", in a similar fashion.

Note:

1. I was more minimal in my interface design (I took care only of the Status part, not even the name).
2. As per the description of your description, I think something much more detailed is needed for status, even a class for itself. Status seems a complex thing where you want to read / store various information (like a boolean value to tell if is it good or not + a description or what is the issue if any). But below I kepty status as a simple string for a start.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public interface HasStatus
{
    string Status { get; set; }
}

public class Battery : HasStatus
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class Camera : HasStatus
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Cpu : HasStatus
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Temperature { get; set; }
    public string Ram { get; set; }
    public string Utilisation { get; set; }
}

class HelloWorld {
  static void Main() {
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    
    var allMyStuff = new List<HasStatus>
    {
        new Camera { Id = 111, Status = "Good" },
        new Camera { Id = 200, Status = "Sensor has a problem" },
        new Camera { Id = 304, Status = "Good" },
        new Camera { Id = 467, Status = "Good" },
        new Cpu { Status = "Doesn't run very fast", Ram = "1MB" },
        new Battery { Value = "a lot", Status = "Good" }
    };
    
    int i = 0;
    foreach (var stuff in allMyStuff)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Status of object N° {i} of type {stuff.GetType().Name} is '{stuff.Status}'");
        i++;
    }
        
  }
}
```

You can filter the not-good ones, for instance with :

```
var allNotGoodStuff = allMyStuff.Where(x => x.Status != "Good");

foreach (var badStuff in allNotGoodStuff)
{
    // Do some display or anything else with each bad stuff here...

}
```