# Using a Dictionary<string, Type> to use the value as type of a list

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, generics

I am trying to build a solution fitting with the problem of not knowing what kind of Setting type I am dealing with.

I got a `Dictionary<string, Type>` (which I initially wanted to make `<string, class>` but that didn't work)

that I want to fill with the setting code and the type of class attached to it i.e.
`{ "person_customField", typeof(CustomFieldModel) }`

Why I want to do this is because I have a field in my database filled with json data that should be deserialized to a `List<>` but I don't know what kind of setting it is until I get the object from the database. I can use the `Code` field to detemine what type it is (`person_CustomField` should use the `CustomFieldModel` class, but `emailSetting` should use `EmailSettingModel` to match parameters to.

Is there a way to successfully make this statement work with? 
`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SettingTypes[record.SettingCode]>>(record.SettingValues).ToList<ISetting>()`
Or should I go a different route

Code Sample:

```
    public static readonly Dictionary<string, Type> SettingTypes = new Dictionary<string, Type>()
    {
        { "person_CustomFields", typeof(CustomFieldModel)},
    };


    public static TenantSettingEdit ConvertToTenantSettingEdit(this T_TenantSetting rec)
    {
        var test = SettingTypes[rec.TENS_Code];

        TenantSettingEdit item = new TenantSettingEdit()
        {
            IDToken = rec.TENS_TenantSettingID.toVirtualGuid().ToString(),
            Code = rec.TENS_Code,
            Settings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SettingTypes[rec.TENS_Code]>>(rec.TENS_Setting).ToList<ITenantSetting>(),
            IsActive = rec.TENS_ActiveRec,

        };
        return item;
    }
```

(I have done this before with PHP but I am not sure if this is even remotely possible with C#)

Comment: The generic argument (e.g. the `T` in `List<T>`)  is a **compile-time**-thing, which happens when you *build/compile* your assembly. How would you expect the compiler to infer a type provided at **runtime**, which is when you *execute* your program? The only thing to do is let all possible types implement a common base-class or an interface and use that type as generic constraint for your list.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. I got an ISettings interface that kind of connects it all, but I think I will solve it in a different way, having a Convert function on the different settingtypes and calling it like `SettingTypes[rec.TENS_Code].ConvertToTenantSettingEdit(rec);`

Comment: However this will probably also just return an `ISettings`.

Answer (score 1):

> Why I want to do this is because I have a field in my database filled
> with json data that should be deserialized to a List<> but I don't
> know what kind of setting it is until I get the object from the
> database.

If you're using Json.Net for JSON serialization/deserialization you can use the [TypeNameHandling](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_TypeNameHandling.htm) property to embed Type information in the resulting JSON. That JSON can the be deserialized by Json.Net without additional information. If it is necessary to map custom values to the types instead of the automatically generated ones you can use a [SerializationBinder](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultSerializationBinder.htm) (check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12203624/4420762) answer).

If none of those help you, you can still fall back to reflection in the way [M Kloster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51516572/4420762) describes.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a variable as the type parameter in the code, no. What you need to do is to generate the type-specific method by reflection:

```
var genericMethod = ((Func<string, int>)Json.DeserializeObject<int>).Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition();
var boundMethod = genericMethod.MakeGenericMethod(SettingTypes[record.SettingCode]);
var result = boundMethod.Invoke(null, rec.TENS_Setting)...
```