# Is it possible to tell Newtonsoft to map a declared $type to a different type when deserialising?

Tags: json, .net, json.net

I have many serialized objects that have a `$type` property that I'd like to deserialize. However, I want to tell Newtonsoft to map to different type depending on the value of `$type`,

How can I do this?

E.g.

```json
{
    "$type": "A.B.C, A.B",
    "MyProp": "MyValue"
}
```

I'd like Newtonsoft to interpret this as:

```json
{
    "$type": "A.B.D, A.B",
    "MyProp": "MyValue"
}
```

Comment: Sure, you can use a [custom serialization binder](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeSerializationBinder.htm).  See [Using a custom type discriminator to tell JSON.net which type of a class hierarchy to deserialize](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11099466/3744182).  Do the answers to that question fully answer your question also, or do you need something more specific?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for - thanks. If you post as an answer I'll accept it.