# Serializing/deserializing derived objects in SignalR

Tags: json.net, signalr

I am using SignalR 1.1 with .NET clients.
I have a single method in my hub that accepts an object of BaseMessage class and broadcasts it to all clients:

```
public void SendMessage(BaseMessage message)
{
    Clients.All.BroadCastMessage(message);
}
```

Clients will pass derived messages into this method:

```
_hub.Invoke("SendMessage", new ErrorMessage("Some Error")).Wait();
```

The client has a single message handler:

```
_hub.On<BaseMessage>("BroadCastMessage", OnMessageReceived);
```

I've specified TypeNameHandling.All serializer settings at application startup:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All};
var serializer = new JsonNetSerializer(settings);
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(IJsonSerializer), () => serializer);
```

But when the client sends a derived message, the server receives a base message.

How should I configure serializer to be able to receive derived messages?

Note: I can do serialization/deserialization manually and pass strings to the server, but this causes double serialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SignalR is not supporting this scenario as it would require your JSON payload to contain information about the derived type and assembly. See this [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348215/how-to-deserialize-json-into-ienumerablebasetype-with-newtonsoft-json-net).
Adding type information in your payload would not play well with browsers. I suggest you create individual hub methods to handle each of your derived types.