# SignalR Serialization issue

Tags: c#, signalr, jsonserializer

Signalr Hub Client trying to call Subscribe method of Hub with object of TopicFilter which doesn't de-serialize properly in hub. The type received in Subsribe is Filter whereas i want TopicFilter object in there. It works if i manual serialize and deserialize using JsonSerializer class but i want signalr jasonSerilizer to do it as there will be lot of places if i have to do manually. Any thoughts on this?

```
hub = connection.CreateHubProxy("DebugDispatcherHub");
hub.JsonSerializer.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto;
hub.JsonSerializer.TypeNameAssemblyFormat = FormatterAssemblyStyle.Full;

var topicfilter = new TopicFilter() { Topic = new Guid("5D5B26AD-5E6A-4B96-95C8-06540FC17E53") };
 hub.Invoke("Subscribe", filter); 

public class Filter { }

public  class TopicFilter : Filter
{
    public Guid Topic { get; set; }
}

[HubName("DebugDispatcherHub")]
public class DebugDispatcherHub : Hub
{
     public void Subscribe(Filter filter)
     {
         //some code here
     }
}

internal class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.MapSignalR();
        var service = (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer)GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer));
        service.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto  ;
        service.TypeNameAssemblyFormat = FormatterAssemblyStyle.Full;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just change the type of the argument of Subscribe to TopicFilter?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have more filters like TypeFilter and EventFilter being passed to Subscribe as well, So i want a generic type there.

Comment: Are you using any DI container (ie your own implementation of IDependencyResolver) ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Serializing/deserializing derived objects in SignalR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636415/serializing-deserializing-derived-objects-in-signalr)