# Deserializing inherited classes

Tags: c#, json, serialization, asp.net-web-api2

I want to send parameter-settings from a backendapplication to the frontend. I also need to be able to have different type of parameters (Portnumbers, folders, static strings and such).

So I've designed a baseclass, Parameter as such:

```
public abstract class Parameter
{
    public abstract bool isValid();
}
```

Let's say that we have two types of folder parameters:

```
public abstract class Folder : Parameter
{
    public string folderName { get; set; }

    protected Folder(string folderName)
    {
        this.folderName = folderName;
    }
}

public class ReadWriteFolder : Folder
{
    public ReadWriteFolder(string folderName) : base(folderName)
    {
    }

    public override bool isValid()
    {
        return isReadable() && isWritable();
    }
}

public class ReadFolder : Folder
{
    public ReadFolder(string folderName) : base(folderName)
    {
    }

    public override bool isValid()
    {
        return isReadable();
    }
}
```

This is used from a WebAPI, so this is my controller:

```
public Dictionary<String, Parameter> Get()
{ 
    Dictionary<String, Parameter> dictionary  = new Dictionary<String, Parameter>();
    dictionary.Add("TemporaryFiles", new ReadWriteFolder("C:\\temp\\"));
    dictionary.Add("AnotherTemporaryFiles", new ReadWriteFolder("D:\\temp\\"));

    return dictionary;
}
```

This yields the following JSON-serialisation:
 `{"TemporaryFiles":{"folderName":"C:\\temp\\"},"AnotherTemporaryFiles":{"folderName":"D:\\temp\\"}}` which seems reasonable.

My question is this: How can I deserialize this back into the original types? Or change the serialization into something that is more easy to deserialize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you using for serialization?  If it's JSON.Net (which many here would suggest!), there's a number of realted questions:

[how to deserialize JSON into IEnumerable with Newtonsoft JSON.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348215/how-to-deserialize-json-into-ienumerablebasetype-with-newtonsoft-json-net)

But the crux is the type name handling, which will decorate the elements with the type information to be able to deserialize them:

```
 JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
 {
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
 };

string strJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictionary, settings);
```

And then you should be able to deserialize directly.

```
var returnDictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<String, Parameter>>(strJson, settings)
```

Comment: This was the clue! I actually didn't know that I used JSON.net (i've just used the one provided with the WebAPI-template). As soon as I'd set the TypeNameHandling parameter everything worked as I intended. Thanks!