# JsonConvert convert to custom object

Tags: c#, json.net

I made a simple custom `JsonConvert` class. Right now I'm trying to convert the JSON data to a custom class like so:

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    //JObject jo = JObject.Load(reader);
    MyItem instance = serializer.Deserialize<MyItem>(reader);

    // want to do more thing here...
}
```

Every time it executes the `Deserialize<>()`  method it re-enters the `ReadJson` method and thus keeping me in a never ending loop.

How can I convert the JSON data to my custom object without ending up in a never ending loop?

---

### Updated

The JSON I'm receiving is generic. I need the custom converter to map it to the right type. The JSON looks like this:

```
{
    /* Base obj properties, should be mapped to Page.cs */
    "$type": "App.Models.Page, App",
    "title": "Page title",
    "technicalName": "some_key",
    "fields": [

        /* Should be mapped to InputField.cs */
        {
            "$type": "App.Models.InputField, App",
            "type": "input",
            "typeTitle": "Input",
            "title": "Input",
            "technicalName": "input",
            "inputType": "text",
            "defaultValue": "Input default value"
        },

        /* Should be mapped to TextareaField.cs */
        {
            "$type": "App.Models.TextareaField, App",
            "type": "textarea",
            "typeTitle": "Textarea",
            "title": "Textarea",
            "technicalName": "textarea",
            "defaultValue": "default textarea value"
        }
    ]
}
```

In short my class files look like this:

```
class Page
{
    public string Title {get;set;}
    public string TechnicalName {get;set;}

    public List<Field> Fields {get;set;} // Note the base class "Field"
}

class InputField : Field // Field has base properties
{
 // InputField has its own properties
}

class TextareaField : Field // Field has base properties
{
 // TextareaField has its own properties
}
```

### TypeNameHandling

I've set the json formatters settings:

```
jsonOutputFormatter.SerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects;
jsonInputFormatter.SerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto;
```

When I output a `Page` object through `Web API` then I get a JSON structure exactly like the one above. When I sent back that exact JSON data I expect it to nicely map back to a `Page` object with the correct types in the `Field` list property.

But all the `Fields` are mapped to its base class `Field` instead of the types that are defined in `$type`.

So currently the JSON formatter works great for outputting. It shows all the `$type`s. But the input mapping isn't really mapping back to its specific types.

Comment: Why did you create a custom `JsonConvert` in the first place? Why not use the one provided by the library?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Because I have a page that posts a JSON array which can be of a generic type. I'm eventually going to use the custom converter to map it back to the right type.

Comment: You can try changing the method signature to `public new object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)`

Comment: @JurgenCamilleri Doesn't work, it's an abstract method that needs to be overridden.

Comment: @Vivendi Post your JSON structure.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Added the JSON

Comment: Are you serializing with Json.NET as well?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov The `Web Api` serializes my object. I don't need any custom methods for that.

Comment: Then read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348215/how-to-deserialize-json-into-ienumerablebasetype-with-newtonsoft-json-net) answer.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8031283/567073) might help

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov That is exactly what I want to do. Serializing objects gives me the `$type` of each object in JSON. Unfortunately, sending that JSON data back doesn't map its generic objects back to the specified `$type` when its Deserialized by the Web API.

Comment: Because you need to tell the `JsonFormatter` to use `TypeNameHandling.All`

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov You are right. I was hoping I could get away with `Objects` only, since that makes a cleaner JSON structure. But using `All` will do fine also in my case. Could you please provide this as an answer so I have something to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you use Json.NET on the Web API side, you don't need a custom `JsonConverter`. You can explicitly tell the `JsonFormatter` (which internally uses Json.NET) to use [`TypeNameHandling.All`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_TypeNameHandling.htm). That way, it'll know exactly which type to deserialize given an `IEnumerable<BaseType>`. More on that can be find in [how to deserialize JSON into IEnumerable<BaseType> with Newtonsoft JSON.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348215/how-to-deserialize-json-into-ienumerablebasetype-with-newtonsoft-json-net)

Answer (score 1):

```
public static class ConvertToJson
{ 
    public static T Deserialize<T>(string json)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json)))
        {
            DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
            return (T)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
        }
    }
}
```