# Convert JSON to list with generic types

Tags: c#, json, .net

I got a JSON response like:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "document": {
        "id": "123",
        "title": "title2",
        "description": "Description1",
        "type": "Typ1"
      }
    },
    {
      "document": {
        "id": "456",
        "title": "title2",
        "description": "desctiption2",
        "type": "Type2",
        "Type2Property": "Type2Property"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see above I have two values (just for example) with different properties.
In my code, I have two classes.

```
public class Type1
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public class Type2
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Type2Property {get; set;}
}
```

Question: How can I create one generic list which combines Type1 and Type2.  In the future, I can have more TypeX (with different properties). So, I'd like to parse JSON into a generic list.

Update: I can filter json by the Type property from the JSON.

Comment: Through inheritance

Comment: I can have a different classes with different properties.

Comment: You need to serialize it with the type information, instead of using your own Type property - see [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348215/how-to-deserialize-json-into-ienumerablebasetype-with-newtonsoft-json-net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348215/how-to-deserialize-json-into-ienumerablebasetype-with-newtonsoft-json-net)

Comment: You can use this: https://github.com/dmitry-bym/JsonKnownTypes

Comment: Inherit `Type2` from `Type1`.

Comment: or you can also have a single class only which is `Type2`

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this problem is to create a custom `JsonConverter` and override its `ReadJson` method.

I've introduced a couple of helper classes to be able to parse the whole sample json:

```cs
public class TopLevel
{
    public MidLevel[] Items { get; set; }
}

public class MidLevel
{
    public IDocument Document { get; set; }

}

[JsonConverter(typeof(DocumentTypeConverter))]
public interface IDocument
{
}
```

- I've created an `IDocument` marker interface. If you wish you can use `abstract class`.
- I've decorated the interface with a `JsonConverterAttribute` and specified there the custom converter.
- I've changed the `Type1` and `Type2` classes to implement this interface:

```cs
public class Type1 : IDocument
{
    ...
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public class Type2 : IDocument
{
    ...
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Type2Property { get; set; }
}
```

The `DocumentTypeConverter` naive implementation would look like this:
(Obviously you can make more type-safe)

```cs
public class DocumentTypeConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object? value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public override object? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object? existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var jObject = JObject.Load(reader);
        switch (jObject["type"].Value<string>())
        {
            case "Typ1":
                {
                    var obj = new Type1();
                    serializer.Populate(jObject.CreateReader(), obj);
                    return obj;
                }
            case "Type2":
                {
                    var obj = new Type2();
                    serializer.Populate(jObject.CreateReader(), obj);
                    return obj;
                }
            default:
                throw new Exception();
        }
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) 
        => objectType == typeof(IDocument);
}
```

- The `CanConvert` tells us that this convert can be used against `IDocument`s.
- The ReadJson branches its logic based on the "type" field.
- The actual conversion done with the `Populate` instead of `JsonCovert.Deserialize` to [avoid infinite recursion](http://chrisoldwood.blogspot.com/2017/06/stack-overflow-with-custom-jsonconverter.html).

Finally, the usage is that simple:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var sampleJson = File.ReadAllText("sample.json");
    var sample = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TopLevel>(sampleJson);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```