# Json deserialize to an object with list of derived generic class

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, polymorphism

Let's say I have these classes:

```
public class MachineResult
{
   public string Id {get; set;}
   public List<Base> Results {get; set;}
}

public class Base
{
   public string Name {get; set;}
}

public class Derived<T> : Base
{
    public T Value {get; set;}
}
```

And I am doing the following:

```
MachineResult machineResult = new MachineResult
{
    Id = "x",
    Results = new List<Base>()
};

var temp = new Derived<int>
{
  Name = "y",
  Value = 5
};
machineResult.Results.Add(temp);
```

I can easily serialize these with Newtonsoft's Json serializer.
DOT Net3.1's System.Text.Json serializer can not serialize with the Generic Derived class. That's why I chose Newtonsoft instead of System.Text.Json.

However, when I want to deserialize the Json string into a MachineResult, I get a list full with base classes instead of the derived generic classes. I do understand that the serializer can not know which type is inside that string and make the right derived class for it.

However, I want to be able to deserialize a valid jsonString into the object: MachineResult, containing a list of derived generic classes. I've tried the basic thing:

```
MachineResult deserializedResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MachineResult>(jsonString);
```

It results in a MachineResult object with just a list of Base classes. The base classes contain only a name property. I want the generic value type aswell.

Comment: You could use a custom `JsonConverter` as described in [Json.Net Serialization of Type with Polymorphic Child Object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29528648/3744182), [How to implement custom JsonConverter in JSON.NET to deserialize a List of base class objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8030538/3744182) and [Deserializing polymorphic json classes without type information using json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19307752/3744182).

Comment: Or you could use [`TypeNameHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm) as described in [Json.net serialize/deserialize derived types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8513042/3744182) or [how to deserialize JSON into IEnumerable<BaseType> with Newtonsoft JSON.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6348215/3744182) - but watch out for the security risks explained in [TypeNameHandling caution in Newtonsoft Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39565954/3744182).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Json.net serialize/deserialize derived types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513042/json-net-serialize-deserialize-derived-types)